# Docker desktop for windows - Unable to pull image

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using Docker Desktop for windows [Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4] and on Windows 10 64 Bit OS

When I try to pull an image, using the command,

```
docker pull ubuntu
```

I get the following error.

> Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

I get the above error for any image, I try to pull / run (even the helloworld example image)

I have done the following,

1. Since I am behind a company proxy, I have setup the proxy information via the Settings -> Proxies option
2. In the Settings -> Network option, I have tried both the options ( Automatic and Fixed [ 8.8.8.8 ] ) for the DNS Server, and subsequently restarting docker again.
3. I also checked the url [ https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ ] on the browser. I get the following response

   > {"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}

Any other settings/configurations that I need to do, before Docker can pull the image?

Edit 1 - As suggested, I tried doing docker login from both console and UI

Following are the observations

1. I am able to login from my browser to https://hub.docker.com/
2. From Console when I try to login, I get the following error

> Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection
> (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

3. Through the UI (by clicking the System Tray Icon), when I try to login, I get the below exception, but strangely, it gets logged in into my account, when I again click on the System Tray icon and check

> Docker.Core.DockerException    at
> Docker.WPF.ClientConfig.DockerLogin.SetCredentialInStore(DockerLoginCredential
> cred) in
> C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\ClientConfig\DockerLogin.cs:line
> 158    at Docker.WPF.ClientConfig.DockerLogin.OnCredentialChanges(Auth
> cred) in
> C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\ClientConfig\DockerLogin.cs:line
> 112    at Docker.Core.Mediator`1.Raise(T ev) in
> C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\Mediator.cs:line 50    at Docker.WPF.DockerHub.CredentialManager.Store(Credential cred,
> Credential oAuthCred) in
> C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\DockerHub\CredentialManager.cs:line
> 134    at
> Docker.WPF.DockerHub.CredentialManager.d__21.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\DockerHub\CredentialManager.cs:line
> 165
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at Docker.WPF.DockerHub.LoginDialog.d__6.MoveNext()
> in
> C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\DockerHub\LoginDialog.xaml.cs:line
> 46
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
> Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
> MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object
> obj)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
> msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
> IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)    at
> MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
> callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
> Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
> priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
> numArgs)    at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd,
> Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
> MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
> System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
> frame)    at System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(Object booleanBox)    at
> System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog()    at
> Docker.Systray.DockerHubSystrayGroup.OnLoginToDockerHub() in
> C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Systray\DockerHubSystrayGroup.cs:line
> 249    at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key,
> EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
> button, Int32 clicks)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)    at
> System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg,
> IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Answer (score 0):

On you command line can you try this -

`set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_userid:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port`

`docker pull ubuntu`

Answer (score 0):

We can also check Docker Desktop Settings - which proxy it is using

[image: Docker Desktop Set Proxy settings]

You can also manually configure proxy for docker desktop just make sure you are providing correct proxy details -

[image: Docker Desktop Proxy Configuration]